# Unable to retrive Zimbra GPG key for package validation

Tags: software-installation, zimbra

I unistalled Zimbra 8.8.15. When I tried to reinstall it i received this message"
"Unable to retrive Zimbra GPG key for package validation".
I tried a lot of things, reading in this forum, but it doesn;t work.